# save geotools query result in a shape file/csv file

Tags: shapefile, geotools

I have implemented GeoTools Query tutorial. Can someone tell me that how could I apply a query in two shape files at a time and save the results in a new shape file or a csv file.

or even can i save the query results of a single shape file as done in the Query Tutorial in a new shape file or csv file?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply your `Query` to as many shapefiles as you like just loop through them and keep adding to the feature collection where you are storing the answers.

So in pseudocode:

```
 collection = new List
 for file in shapefiles:
      collection.add(file.queryResult(query));

 writeShapefile(collection);
```

You can actually use a normal Java ArrayList (or Set) to store the results in and then use a ListFeatureCollection to write them out.

FeatureCollection features = new ListFeatureCollection(schema, feats);

**Caveat**: All your shapefiles must have the same contents (or your Query must only extract the common attributes). See my answer to [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/165471/create-shapefile-based-on-geojson-data-with-geotools-java) for an example of ShapeFile writing.